# how to automatically compute whether all groups have the same number of rows, and if not how to search which group lacks which row

Tags: r, dataframe

My data is:

```
data <- structure(list(country = c("Poland", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland", 
                                 "Poland", "Poland", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", 
                                 "Portugal", "Portugal", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
                                 "Spain"), Code = c("POL", "POL", "POL", "POL", "POL", "POL", 
                                                    "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "ESP", "ESP", "ESP", 
                                                    "ESP", "ESP", "ESP"), year = c(1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 
                                                                                   1955, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 
                                                                                   1954, 1955), democracy = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                              1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
                                                                                                                                                8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L), class = "data.frame")
```

And my two vectors are:

```
id.b0 <- c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)

re.b0 <- c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  3L, 3L, 3L)
```

Suppose I decide to combine the vectors and “data”, as:

```
data <- cbind.data.frame(
data, id.b0,
re.b0)
```

I receive an error as:

[image]

This is natural, because I have purposefully deleted one column for Spain  (year 1955) before.

My question is the following:

Is it possible to construct a code that would automatically compute whether all countries have the equal number of years, and if not show which country lacks which year (in my example, it had to show something like “error – Spain, year - 1955).

This would be very helpful when working with large datasets with many number of countries each with many years.
Otherwise, I first receive an error message, then I have to manually examine every country and every year, and this is a real pain in the back.

Comment: try using `count` function

Comment: "*Is it possible to construct a code that would automatically compute whether all countries have the equal number of years, and if not show which country lacks which year (in my example, it had to show something like “error – Spain, year - 1955)*" -- Your question asks for something different than the accepted answer suggests.

Comment: @Friede  well, not exactly. The codes that the guys have provided can automatically identify the missing values (years), and this is already considerably simplifies the problem. But if you can write the code that can do exactly what I have described, you would be more than welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also make use of `tidyr::complete` to get back deleted/unavailable combinations.  Below mentioned code will find out missing years for each country, that may not necessarily be in sequence as shown by other answerer.  Try this on any possible combination, I think this should work.

The `complete` function with use of `nesting` will bring all the possible combinations in data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(country = c("Poland", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland", 
                                   "Poland", "Poland", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", 
                                   "Portugal", "Portugal", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
                                   "Spain"), Code = c("POL", "POL", "POL", "POL", "POL", "POL", 
                                                      "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "ESP", "ESP", "ESP", 
                                                      "ESP", "ESP"), year = c(1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 
                                                                                     1955, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 
                                                                                     1954), democracy = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
data
#>     country Code year democracy
#> 1    Poland  POL 1950         3
#> 2    Poland  POL 1951         3
#> 3    Poland  POL 1952         3
#> 4    Poland  POL 1953         3
#> 5    Poland  POL 1954         3
#> 6    Poland  POL 1955         3
#> 7  Portugal  PRT 1950         1
#> 8  Portugal  PRT 1951         1
#> 9  Portugal  PRT 1952         1
#> 10 Portugal  PRT 1953         1
#> 11 Portugal  PRT 1954         1
#> 12 Portugal  PRT 1955         1
#> 13    Spain  ESP 1950         1
#> 14    Spain  ESP 1951         1
#> 15    Spain  ESP 1952         1
#> 16    Spain  ESP 1953         1
#> 17    Spain  ESP 1954         1
id.b0 <- c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)

re.b0 <- c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  3L, 3L, 3L)


data %>% 
  tidyr::complete(country, nesting(year), fill = list(Code = NA, democracy = NA)) %>% 
  cbind(id.b0, re.b0)
#>     country year Code democracy id.b0 re.b0
#> 1    Poland 1950  POL         3     1     1
#> 2    Poland 1951  POL         3     2     1
#> 3    Poland 1952  POL         3     3     1
#> 4    Poland 1953  POL         3     4     1
#> 5    Poland 1954  POL         3     5     1
#> 6    Poland 1955  POL         3     6     1
#> 7  Portugal 1950  PRT         1     1     2
#> 8  Portugal 1951  PRT         1     2     2
#> 9  Portugal 1952  PRT         1     3     2
#> 10 Portugal 1953  PRT         1     4     2
#> 11 Portugal 1954  PRT         1     5     2
#> 12 Portugal 1955  PRT         1     6     2
#> 13    Spain 1950  ESP         1     1     3
#> 14    Spain 1951  ESP         1     2     3
#> 15    Spain 1952  ESP         1     3     3
#> 16    Spain 1953  ESP         1     4     3
#> 17    Spain 1954  ESP         1     5     3
#> 18    Spain 1955 <NA>        NA     6     3
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Added `arrange(country, year) %>%` and the issue you pointed out is fixed. Tested on subsetted data with extra rows removed and it works :)

Comment: @LTyrone, No I meant you are filling values based on arithmetic sequence while my code doesn't rely on having sequential values in `year` field.

Comment: Aaah, cool. To clarify, am I right to assume this means 1) your solution is not dependent on each group having the same min and max? 2) And also that a group can skip some years but still create groups of equal length? Or just the latter?

Comment: @LTyrone,  Yes `year` column can have non-sequential values and code will replicate all values in each group `nesting`

Comment: Thank you all guys for your awesome code! It all worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wide format table,
using `pivot_wider()` (tidyverse) or `dcast()` (data.table).

Since yourt sample data is complete, the below example is filled with value 1, but for incomplete data 0's appear for the missing country-year combinations.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(data), country ~ year, value.var = "year", fun.aggregate = length)
# Key: <country>
#   c  ountry  1950  1951  1952  1953  1954  1955
#      <char> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:   Poland     1     1     1     1     1     1
# 2: Portugal     1     1     1     1     1     1
# 3:    Spain     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

For example, dropping the first, ninth and twelfth row results in incomplete data, and you'll get the following output:

```
dcast(setDT(data)[-c(1,9,12),], country ~ year, value.var = "year", fun.aggregate = length)
# Key: <country>
#     country  1950  1951  1952  1953  1954  1955
#      <char> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:   Poland     0     1     1     1     1     1
# 2: Portugal     1     1     0     1     1     0
# 3:    Spain     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you, actually this is an option! My concern is that the visual examination of the output where 30-40 countries each with 70-80 years are involved might still be hard.

Answer (score 1):

This should scale to as many years as you need, and avoids having to go through and check for incomplete data. There is still an issue with your example data (you only deleted the row number and not the entire row), so I have provided an updated version. This method `arrange()`s the countries and dates in sequence, `complete()`s the sequence of years based on the min and max year values in the year column, `fill()s` the rest of the columns, and adds your vectors:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- structure(list(country = c("Poland", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland", 
                                   "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal",
                                   "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain"), 
                       Code = c("POL", "POL", "POL", "POL", "POL", "POL",
                                "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", 
                                "ESP", "ESP", "ESP", "ESP", "ESP"), 
                       year = c(1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 
                                1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 
                                1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954), 
                      democracy = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                                    1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), 
                  row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
                                10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L), 
                  class = "data.frame")

id.b0 <- c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)

re.b0 <- c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  3L, 3L, 3L)

data %>% 
  group_by(country) %>%
  arrange(country, year) %>%
  complete(year = seq(min(data$year), max(data$year), 1)) %>%
  fill(Code, democracy, .direction = "downup") %>%
  bind_cols(id.b0 = id.b0, re.b0 = re.b0) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 18 × 6
   country   year Code  democracy id.b0 re.b0
   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <int> <int>
 1 Poland    1950 POL           3     1     1
 2 Poland    1951 POL           3     2     1
 3 Poland    1952 POL           3     3     1
 4 Poland    1953 POL           3     4     1
 5 Poland    1954 POL           3     5     1
 6 Poland    1955 POL           3     6     1
 7 Portugal  1950 PRT           1     1     2
 8 Portugal  1951 PRT           1     2     2
 9 Portugal  1952 PRT           1     3     2
10 Portugal  1953 PRT           1     4     2
11 Portugal  1954 PRT           1     5     2
12 Portugal  1955 PRT           1     6     2
13 Spain     1950 ESP           1     1     3
14 Spain     1951 ESP           1     2     3
15 Spain     1952 ESP           1     3     3
16 Spain     1953 ESP           1     4     3
17 Spain     1954 ESP           1     5     3
18 Spain     1955 ESP           1     6     3
```